# Is there a Linux command that does nothing, but never exits?

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a Linux command that does literally nothing, doesn't output anything, but stays alive until `^C`.

`while true; do; done` is not a good solution, because it is CPU intensive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add a `sleep` command.

```
while true; do sleep 600; done
```

will sleep for 10 minutes between loops.

Comment: You're thinking too small, just go with `sleep 999999999`. It saves the hassle of a shell script and forking another process every ten minutes. :)

Comment: GNU sleep will take "infinity" as an argument, too

Comment: @Jeff, so will the `sleep` builtin of `ksh93`, but not that of `mksh`.

Answer (score 26):

If we look at *system calls*, there's actually one that does exactly that, [`pause`(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html):

> `pause()` causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a
>          signal is delivered ...

Of course, then we'd just need a program that uses it. Short of compiling the two-liner C program below, the easiest way is probably with Perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e pause
```

In C:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void) { return pause(); }
```

Answer (score 19):

GNU `sleep` and the `sleep` builtin of `ksh93` (but not `mksh`) accept any floating point number, not just integers, so you can do this:

```
sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 16):

Since you've mentioned ctrl-C I assume that you want to use it in interactive terminal. So you may just wait for input.

```
$ read
```

or just use arbitrary other commands which read from stdin like `cat`. They do "nothing" as long as there is no input.

```
$ cat >/dev/null
```

or even better without using stdin:

```
$ tail -f <<EOF
EOF
```

Comment: This may however be tricky in a shell script if standard input is being looped over and `read` or `cat` incorrectly consume from that...

Comment: as a variant that doesn't use stdin:  `tail -f /an/existing/regular/file  >/dev/null` :  this will sit waiting for new addition to /an/existing/regular/file  (doesn't work on some files:   tail -f /dev/null    will exit immediately. But will work for all regular files. If that file is not growing, the command will eat little cpu)

Comment: @rudimeier : well the "<(true)" part is not really portable in itself, if one happen to use "old bashes" or other old shells with no support for "<(...)"

Comment: @OlivierDulac found the trick, see my edited answer.

Comment: @rudimeier: nice, but just do a regular `tail -f <<EOF` to be a tiny bit more portable ^^ (you already have +1 from me anyway)

Comment: @OlivierDulac thanks, this was a typo, not a wanted bashism ;)

Answer (score 6):

you can:

```
tail -f /an/existing/regular/file >/dev/null
```

This will not use stdin (as `read` would) and will sit waiting for new addition to /an/existing/regular/file (doesn't work on some files: `tail -f /dev/null` will exit immediately. But will work for all regular files. If that file is not growing, the command will eat little cpu)

Comment: Except on systems that use APIs like Linux' inotify, that will typically do one `read()` system call per second though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, it is not "doing nothing", but hopefully not much. I'm sure there are better options out there (sleep being quite good already), I just showed an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Not for forever, but there is `sleep`.  You could combine your `while` loop with sleep - doesn't even seem to tickle the cpus in my `gkrellm` monitor.
dr01 types faster than I do :) ... so more info - your cpu spiking is because it has to continually process the logic check with no pause between....

```
while true
do
  sleep 100
done
```

Or as a one-liner

`while true; do sleep 100; done`

Comment: Thank you both. Adding sleep indeed solves CPU load problem.