# How to prevent a bash script to close

Tags: shell-script

How can I prevent a bash script from closing, so block itself from closing.

Is there a command that executes a command if there is no action?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se] **:-)** `while : ; do done;` anywhere inside your bash script or at the end will prevent a bash script from closing but that'll be of very little use.  Can you [edit] your question and provide the current bash script that you're trying to prevent to close?

Comment: Despite deleting and recreating this question, we still aren't clear on what you are asking. A shell script typically runs through its commands and then exits (closes, ends, etc.) Some programs, which may be bash scripts, can remain open and behave interactively with a users input or other externals. But if a script comes to the end, it finishes, closes, exits. Your question comes across like "how can I prevent the Night from ending?" Perhaps reconsider your problem and edit the question to ask a different aspect of the problem?

Comment: I think this is what he's looking for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836

Comment: Just like me, maybe you also find useful this article explaining the basics of the best ways how to properly end a shell script: https://web.archive.org/web/20230604212552/https://www.baeldung.com/linux/safely-exit-scripts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your other (now deleted) question, it seems you want to run

```
xterm -e your-script
```

And the terminal emulator window not to go away after the script finishes.

For that, you could add a command that sleeps forever at the end of your script, or in an EXIT trap. See [How to do nothing forever in an elegant way?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42901) or [Is there a Linux command that does nothing, but never exits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366077) for some options.

```
trap 'sleep infinity' EXIT
```

Would cause the shell to run `sleep infinity` upon exit, and so never exit. With those `sleep` implementations that don't support `infinity`, replace with a large number, like `sleep 2147483647` (the largest 32 bit signed integer which should be safe on most systems and is about 68 years).

With `xterm`, you can also use its `-hold` option which is designed for that.

Comment: **:D +1** for 68 years!

Comment: This can be accomplished in `gnome-terminal` too; see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal/1209836#1209836.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of blocking can be using a user input to block. Try using `read varname` at the end program so that it will keep waiting for user input and will not exit.